# Mailchimp Batch Call returning 0 Total Operations

Tags: php, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I've been banging my head all day to get batches to work when subscribing contacts to a specific list in Mailchimp. I get the following response when I attempt the call, which says my total_operations is 0. Any idea's on where to start to find out what I'm doing wrong? Any help might save me from insanity and is greatly appreciated!

Here is how the data is set up. I'm fairly certain everything is correct here.

```
$finalData = [];
foreach ($list_clean as $obj) {
    $individulData = array(
        'email_address' => $obj->email_address,
        'status'        => 'subscribed',
        'merge_fields'  => array(
            'FNAME' => $obj->first_name,
            'LNAME' => $obj->last_name
        )
    );

    $json_individulData        = json_encode($individulData);
    $finalData['operations'][] =
        array(
            "method" => "PUT",
            "path"   => "/lists/$mc_lid/members/" . md5(strtolower($obj->email_address)),
            "body"   => $json_individulData
        );
}
```

This returns data in this format: (modified date content, but structure is the same)

```
{
  "operations": [
    {
      "method": "PUT",
      "path": "/lists/281c77a710/members/d83c093eb534d5c94169414a2477b13f",
      "body": "{\"email_address\":\"test1@example.com\",\"status\":\"subscribed\",\"merge_fields\":{\"FNAME\":\"Test\",\"LNAME\":\"One\"}}"
    },
    {
      "method": "PUT",
      "path": "/lists/281c77a710/members/c48dc4970fabd67cebd24b9102c1b38c",
      "body": "{\"email_address\":\"test2@example.com\",\"status\":\"subscribed\",\"merge_fields\":{\"FNAME\":\"Test\",\"LNAME\":\"Two\"}}"
    }
}
```

And here's the function that makes the call.

```
function batchSubscribe(array $data, $key) {
    $auth          = base64_encode('user:' . $key);
    $json_postData = json_encode($data);
    console_log($json_postData);
    $ch            = curl_init();
    $dataCenter    = substr($key, strpos($key, '-') + 1);
    $curlopt_url   = 'https://' . $dataCenter . '.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/batches/';
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $curlopt_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json',
        'Authorization: Basic ' . $auth));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'PHP-MCAPI/3.0');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json_postData);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    return $result;
}
```

It doesn't return any errors but the total_operations always comes back as 0. Here is the full response.

```
{
  "id": "dd9c7632ab",
  "status": "pending",
  "total_operations": 0,
  "finished_operations": 0,
  "errored_operations": 0,
  "submitted_at": "2019-03-18T22:18:56+00:00",
  "completed_at": "",
  "response_body_url": "",
  "_links": [
    {
      "rel": "parent",
      "href": "https://us20.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/batches",
      "method": "GET",
      "targetSchema": "https://us20.api.mailchimp.com/schema/3.0/Definitions/Batches/CollectionResponse.json",
      "schema": "https://us20.api.mailchimp.com/schema/3.0/CollectionLinks/Batches.json"
    },
    {
      "rel": "self",
      "href": "https://us20.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/batches/dd9c7632ab",
      "method": "GET",
      "targetSchema": "https://us20.api.mailchimp.com/schema/3.0/Definitions/Batches/Response.json"
    },
    {
      "rel": "delete",
      "href": "https://us20.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/batches/dd9c7632ab",
      "method": "DELETE"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I received a response from the Mailchimp support team, and they informed me that the response always returns 0 total_operations. So it was working all along, just took a bit to update the list in Mailchimp.